# Database structure for a bank with customers who have multiple accounts

Tags: database-design

I'm having trouble seeing the best way to set up a database for a simple bank with customers that have multiple accounts.  I imagine a basic table as below, to start with:

**Customers**

[image]

But what do we put in the Accounts field?  It seems that the thing that needs to go here is a pointer to a complete table, like "Customer_1_accounts" , Customer_2_accounts", etc. 
How is this normally handled?

Thanks

Comment: You've got it backwards; create an `Accounts` table, with a foreign key that points back to the `CustomerId` in the `Customers` table

Comment: or amybe use a junction table?

Comment: Ok.  So that means that the bank has one HUGE table with all its accounts in the world, and for Customer's 2 account, above,  the "owner" field in that row will be the ID for Customer 2 - is that right?

Comment: This is for homework, I hope?

Comment: This is most probably a homework. On the same page he has another question about a website builder database design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
Customers
-----------
Id
Address
Phone

Account
-----------
Id
Whatever else
CustomerId
```

This allows customers to have multiple accounts, but accounts can only have one customer.  If you want to allow accounts to have multiple customers (my wife and I share an account for instance) and customers to have multiple accounts then you will need a third table:

```
Customer
--------
Id
Address
Phone

Account
---------
Id
Whatever else

CustomerAccounts
---------------
CustomerId
AccountId
```

**Under no circumstances should you try to stick information about multiple accounts in a single column in the customers table.**  This will make your life a living hell.

Comment: OK. Slightly more complicated: Imagine a company that lets people use their web software to build web sites. So each customer has a site that they've built and each site has hundreds of "cells" that are certainly only in this particular site. From from your example, we would have a HUGE "cell"  table with every cell created by every customer (millions) and then each cell record would describe its HTML,etc and have a pointer back to the containing site. It seems that one table with every cell ever built is misdirected.  It seems there should be a "siteId 5 cells" , "siteId 6 cells" table, etc..

Comment: I would not use `Slightly more complicated` to describe this.  I think `Completely different question` is more accurate.  Seriously though this has nothing to do with your original question, and if you need this problem addressed you should create a new question.

Comment: You're right.  Sorry.  I put the new question at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374480/database-for-a-web-site-builder

Answer (score 1):

Customers table:

CustomerID, Address, Phone

Accounts table:
AccountID, CustomerID, etc

The Accounts table keeps track of information about the account including who the owner of the account is.  The Customer table keeps track of information about the customer.  Whenever you have a many to one relationship such as with accounts and customers, the many side (accounts) creates a pointer to the one side (customers)