# Database for a web site builder

Tags: database, database-design, multi-tenant

Imagine a company that lets people use their web software to build web sites. Each customer has one or more sites that they've built and each of these sites will contain perhaps a hundred "cells" that hold the HTML for various pieces of the site. We know for certain that each cell will only be used in one site.  So we have:

[image]

Now we need to describe the cells in each site.

One way would be to have a huge (and I mean huge) cell table that contains all the cells created by a million customers. Then each cell record would point back to the siteId where it was used.

But it seems that there should be a way to take advantage of the knowledge that each cell is only one of a hundred or so in its site, so instead of searching a table of 100 million cells we could search a table of 100 cells, or just ask for that table when we want to build that site.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: You could keep the company specific tables in a separate database. This has the advantages of easily removing it if they go elsewhere and it adds more security to stop company A seeing company B data. You could then have a premium backup service

Comment: Yes, that was my original thought, but now we have a million databases! Is that reasonable?

Comment: It seems a lot. Depending on your database you could add a clustered index and add all the rows into one table. You would also need some contingency planning as a database failure would affect all customers though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One way would be to have a huge (and I mean huge) cell table that
>   contains all the cells created by a million customers. Then in each
>   row of a cell record we'd point back to the siteId where it was used.

This is probably the route I would go. Most modern databases can handle tables with hundreds of millions of rows when you use the proper performance tuning techniques.

I'm not positive but it sounds like you are considering placing cells for each site in a site specific table in an effort to keep the number of rows in each table down.  If this is true it seems like you are trying to over optimize before you have any performance problems.

I would focus on creating a well designed normalized database at this point and if you run into performance problems, I would come back here with the specific performance problem.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do.  Consider that when someone accesses a page the DB will either get a request "Give me all the cells from a list of 100 million that have siteID=5" or "Give me all the cells in the "SiteId_5_cell"  table. There's probably no page parameter more important than load time. (Amazon found that their revenue went up 1% for every 100ms they shaved off page load time.)  So that's why I'm paranoid.  If I can save hundreds of ms with a prebuilt table I'd like to do it.  If we're talking us, I won't bother.